# How do I convert a regular expression match into a "struct"?

Tags: c++, regex, struct, data-conversion

Regular Expression: `([0-9]*)|([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)`
String: `word1 word2 0:12:13.23456` ... example string
match: `0`,`12`,`13.23456`

Requirement:
convert to a struct ->

```cpp
struct Duration {
    unsigned int hours;
    unsigned int minutes;
    double seconds;
};
```

Current matcher:

```cpp
Duration duration;
std::regex regex("([0-9]*):([0-9]*):([0-9]*.[0-9]*)");
auto begin = std::sregex_iterator(data.begin(), data.end(), regex); // data is an std::string instance
auto end = std::sregex_iterator();
for (auto it = begin; it != end; it++) {
    auto match = *it;
    // how to cycle through the data values of the instance of Duration?            
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [`std::regex_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) instead of iterators and loops. Then you get [a match result](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) which you can [index](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/operator_at) to get the separate matches.

Once you have the separate matches, you can call [`std::stoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) or [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) to convert the matched strings to their numeric variants.

Perhaps something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

struct Duration
{
    unsigned int hours;
    unsigned int minutes;
    double seconds;
};

int main()
{
    std::string input = "word1 word2 0:12:13.23456";
    std::regex regex("([0-9]*):([0-9]*):([0-9]*.[0-9]*)");
    std::smatch matches;

    std::regex_search(input, matches, regex);

    Duration duration = {
        static_cast<unsigned int>(std::stoul(matches[1])),
        static_cast<unsigned int>(std::stoul(matches[2])),
        std::stod(matches[3])
    };

    std::cout << "Duration = { " << duration.hours << ", " << duration.minutes << ", " << duration.seconds << " }\n";
}
```

<sub>[Note: There's no error checking, or checking the amount of actual matches in `matches`, which should really be done in a "real" program]</sub>